# Why none of the plugins that have ajax doesn't work in my website?

Tags: plugins, ajax

[This](http://2barnamenevis.com/) is my website. I installed many plugins but if a plugin have ajax, then it doesn't work in main page. can anybody help me?!?

Comment: You included a call to `wp_head()`, right?

Comment: Does the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) not answer all your questions? Try to google before you ask, and if you have, try to explain what that you've seen you find to be confusing or is not functional in your case.

Comment: @m0r7if3r: It's Filter in my country(iran)  and I can't see anything from wordpress.com

Comment: This question is **too localized**, and is also off topic.

Comment: @m0r7if3r: I found wp_head() but in a if:<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: That is not in an `if` statement. The if deals with the enquque, not the `wp_head()` call.

Comment: what am I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at your code, I noticed one huge issue (also pointed out by Milo).  Your script tags (the ones that pull in jQuery and other scripts) are wrong.

For example, this:

```
<script data-djssrc="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/djs"></script>
<script data-djssrc="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/djs"></script>
<script data-djssrc="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/mediaflux.js" type="text/djs"></script>
```

Should really be this:

```
<script src="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/jquery.min.js" type="javascript"></script>
<script src="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="javascript"></script>
<script src="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/mediaflux.js" type="javascript"></script>
```

I did some quick Googling to see if I could find out what was causing this.  I found [some references on the WordPress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-has-changed-my-javascript-code) to a pre-beta feature of CloudFlare causing this issue.  Specifically:

> Yep, turns out it was CloudFlare that was screwing me up. I just got off the phone with support and their explanation was that this feature [beta minify] "is not ready for implementation." I'm still not sure why they have it as an option. FTW. Just disable that, wait about 30 minutes, and you should have your fancy javascript up and working again.

I looked further into your code, and it looks like you are, in fact using CloudFlare:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.__CF=window.__CF||{};window.__CF.u="/cdn-cgi/async/cf/uri/";window.__CF.p="5e/f9847507c0fee91c0268427d3fde85";window.__CF.o=1;window.__CF.c=0;(function(){var a=document,b=a.createElement("script");b.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/v=918368360/cf_tools.min.js";b.setAttribute("async","true");a=a.getElementsByTagName("script");a=a[a.length-1];a.parentNode.insertBefore(b,a)})();
//]]>
</script></body>
```

So just follow the instructions from that forum post - turn off the "beta minify" feature and wait.  This should turn your JavaScript files back to normal and let you use AJAX on your site.

Comment: I have disabled the beta minify feature but there is no change in the plugin!

Comment: From the looks of things, you're also running a cache plugin.  You'll need to disable or flush your cache to regenerate the page content.

Answer (score 2):

One potential issue is that you have two versions of jQuery being loaded, one is probably hardcoded into your theme's `header.php` or at least is not using proper [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) method to include scripts.

```
<script data-djssrc="http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-content/themes/mediaflux2/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/djs"></script>

<script type='text/djs' data-djssrc='http://2barnamenevis.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

Comment: its the code for wp_header: <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee you should remove the first instance hardcoded in your theme, that is not correct and will potentially cause a problem with any plugin that uses jQuery.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee wp_head is not within that if statement, it is functioning correctly.

Comment: It was removed at first.